# UWP : How to "store" ServerCredentials for don't contraint user to login

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient, credentials, basic-authentication

I tried to use **NTLM authentification** for calling WebServices on a UWP app, but it didn't work, and I didn't found any solution:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348489/uwp-and-ntlm-authentification-iis-returns-a-401-5-response)

So I would like to know if it is possible to use the **ServerCredentials** from **HttpBaseProtocolFilter** to store the credentials typed by the user in the prompt window?
[image]

My code is very basic:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ServerCredential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential();
var client = new HttpClient(filter);
```

The first time that I enter it, the login is well saved, but I need to retype the password each time I relaunch the app, even if I check the box "**Remember my credentials**".
This is too constrainant for the users.

***=> Is there a way to store the password too? Or do I need to develop my own login screen?***

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the credentials can be persisted this way over app launches and are cached only for the current session.

The solution for you would be indeed to create your **own login dialog**.

The `PasswordCredential` class allows you to provide the user name and password directly:

```
filter.ServerCredential = new PasswordCredential(
                uri,
                userName,
                password);
```

You can request the user name and password from the user and store them securely [using `PasswordVault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker). Note, that if the user has credential roaming enabled, the credentials will be **roamed across all his devices** (so he will be logged in automatically on other devices where he uses your app).

Comment: Thanks for you return. I've found the same link so I will base myself on this solution.